Proprietary code uses licensed FOSS library: do I have to provide sources?
I'm currently figuring out the licensing implications for a software tool my current employer has made.
They use files covered under EUPL in a proprietary project. As far as I can understand, this is allowed. EUPL does not have the "viral" aspect of e.g. GPL.

The licence (or "license" in US spelling) is reasonably (or moderately/weakly) "copyleft" meaning that derivatives works must stay covered by the same licence in case they are distributed to third parties. But the definition of derivative works depends on the applicable law. If a covered work is modified, it becomes a derivative. But if the normal purpose of the work is to help producing other works (it is a library or a work tool) it would be abusive to consider everything that is produced with the tool as "derivative". Moreover, European law considers that linking two independent works for ensuring their interoperability is authorised regardless of their licence and therefore without changing it: no "viral" effect.
(source)

However, EUPL does give the receiver of the software the right to demand the sources. I wonder... what sources does the distributor need to provide?
I guess there's three possibilities:

All sources of the entire (proprietary) software
Only the files covered by the EUPL
Nothing at all: the software is not licensed as EUPL, and thus proprietary.

Which one is correct?


However, EUPL does give the receiver of the software the right to demand the sources.

Actually, the EUPL requires that you either actively provide the source code, or actively provide a link to a repository containing the source code.

what sources does the distributor need to provide?

Given how the authors of the EUPL look at linking libraries into an application and how that (does not) creates derivative works, the answer intended by the authors of the EUPL is "Only the libraries covered by the EUPL".
Note that your third option (distribute nothing) is impossible, because the EUPL-licensed libraries cannot be distributed under a proprietary license. The only options available are the EUPL itself, or another copyleft license.
